# Define a calculated property on an expando object

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I am working with expando object and I am trying to define a calculated property.

I know that I can define a simple property by doing something like the following:

```
dynamic myExpando = new ExpandoObject();
myExpando.TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything= 42;
```

Likewise, I can also define a method:

```
myExpando.GetTheQuestion = ((Func<string>)(() =>
        {
            return "How many road must a man walk down before we can call him a man?";
        }));
```

When working with a standard object we can define a calculated property, ie define a property that will return the results of a custom method/calc. No need for an example.

I need to do something similar on my expando - having a property that actually calls a "Func" (or some other form of delegate, anything goes as soon as I can call a custom method and have a custom return type). So basically I need to invoke a method like in the second example BUT have it work like a property.

Basically I need to be able to call it with **myExpando.GetTheQuestion** instead of **myExpando.GetTheQuestion()**, while keeping the ability of defining a custom delegate as the property body.

Is there a way to do this? I belive that I *could* do this by using Expression trees, but I admit I am a little lost there. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to achieve this??

---

**EDIT**

Done some more research.. Unless there is some very specific class/interface/sintax that I don't know I am starting to think that the above is impossible. From what I get, the ExpandoObject class works by defining some methods that do the background plumbing - TryGetMember, TrySetMember and such.
Now when "accessing a property" on the dynamic objetc, TryGetMember is the memeber that gets called. That member returns a value from a sort of inner dictionary (yes, I know... this is a little simplified but should give the idea)... no test on the type of value returned. This means that in my example *myExpando.GetTheQuestion* would return the original Func.

It would seem that since TryGetMember just returns a value, there is no way to make it "execute" the property code. To achieve that, you would need some sort of expression/lambda/func/action surrogate which value is actually the RESULT of a method. Which seems impossible (nor would make much sense unless I miss something - basically you would have a value that is set to a 'delegate' and then is get as the delegate return value???). Am I correct or this or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your own ExpandoObject, by inheriting `DynamicObject` and overriding

`public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)` and `public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)`

Implement `TrySetMember` to store the value in a private `Dictionary<string,object>` under `binder.Name` and use `TryGetMember` to retrieve it from that dictionary, that will give you a basic ExpandoObject. Then to give it the feature you need, add a check in `TryGetMember`, after you pull the object, to see if it `is Delagate` and then use reflection to see if it doesn't take any arguments. If both are true just cast to `dynamic` and add no arg invocation parenthesis and assign it to `result`.

```
public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
      if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result)){
           if(result is Delegate && /* some reflection check on args*/){
                result = ((dynamic)result)();
           }
      }
}
```

I have an open source framework ImpromptuInterface (in nuget) that has a *non-sealed* `ImpromptuDictionary` which you could start with as your `ExpandoObject` instead, especially if you need any of the more nuanced features of `ExpandoObject` such as gui binding support. It also has more [dlr plumbing features](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) you might find useful.

Comment: Yes, actually I though about a similar solution - but I was wondering if this should be possible without custom code (not that I couldn't add it - after all my expando object is already a custom inherited class) by using expression trees and such. Anyway, if no other way will be posted, I will accept this as the best fit ^_^

Comment: Ok, for now I will accept this. It is a workaround, but I suppose it is also the only way to have the "calculated property" behave like a normal property. Since I have already extended the base expando to support other behaviours (I use a safe expando that returns null for undefined properties), I guess that I could go with this (actually that was my first idea, but I posted the question anyway to see if I was missing something). Thank jbtule, I will also have a look at your lib - there is always something to learn.